# Receiving 404 error when accessing Item Web Api with Sitecore 7.2

Tags: sitecore-api

Im trying to use the item web api  in sitecore 7.2 to retrieve   https://[hostname]/-/item/v1/sitecore/content/  in postman, but  it returns a 404 not found error (the whole 404 not found html page of the site) anyone have had that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you specifying the authentication parameters? It should look like this in postman.

#### Url

GET: https://yoursite.com/-/item/v1/?sc_itemid={17F19834-7151-4EA7-98F6-393BB85C6868}

#### Headers:

key: X-Scitemwebapi-Username 
value: sitecore\admin

key: X-Scitemwebapi-Password
value: b

#### A site with web api enabled.

Make sure you have your site, in your sites config, with the web api properties.

- itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity"
- itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
- itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"

A config would look like this

```
<site name="MySite" 
  hostName="mysite.com" 
  targetHostName="mysite.com" 
  virtualFolder="/" 
  physicalFolder="/" 
  rootPath="/sitecore/content" 
  startItem="/home" 
  database="web" 
  domain="extranet" 
  allowDebug="true" 
  cacheHtml="true" 
  htmlCacheSize="10MB" 
  registryCacheSize="0" 
  viewStateCacheSize="0" 
  xslCacheSize="5MB" 
  filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
  enablePreview="true" 
  enableWebEdit="true" 
  enableDebugger="true" 
  disableClientData="false" 
  itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity" 
  itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" 
  itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" 
/>
```

Comment: Yeah, it still gives me the whole 404 not found page, look: https://imgur.com/a/usXxR

Comment: It doesnt even gives back a 403, just plain 404

Comment: See my edits above for "A site with web api enabled"